# Is it always true that $\deg[F(\alpha): F(\alpha^2)] = 2$, given $\alpha$ has degree 2 over $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

where $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ and $F$ is characteristic 0.

It seems obvious but I can't seem to think of a good enough proof for it. I am given $\deg[F(\alpha):F] = 2$. And I want to show $\alpha^2 \in F$. So I assumed the negation and tried to prove by contradiction.

Assuming $\alpha^2 \notin F$, we know $\deg[F(\alpha^2):F] \geq 2$ and we know $$\deg[F(\alpha):F] = \deg[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)] \cdot \deg [F(\alpha^2):F]$$
then using this and the fact $\deg[F(\alpha^2):F] \geq  2$, we get $\deg[F(\alpha^2):F] = 2$.

This immediately tells us $F(\alpha) = F(\alpha^2)$. But I don't know how to proceed from here. If we can somehow show that $\deg[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)] = 2$, then we will arrive at the contradiction to show $\alpha^2 \in F$.

Comment: If $\alpha^2+a\alpha+b=0,$ for $a,b\in F$ then it is not true.

Comment: deg$[\mathbb Q(\zeta_6):\mathbb Q(\zeta_3)]=\color{blue}1$, where $\zeta_n$ is an $n^{th}$ root of unity so $\zeta_6^2=\zeta_3$

Comment: Also, if $\alpha^n=1$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  I think my comment is the special case $n=3$ of your last comment

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for the counter-example. Is there any other way to show $\alpha^2 \in F$, when $\alpha$ has degree 2 over $F$? Or is that also not true in general for characteristic 0 field?

Comment: In general, given any polynomial $f(x)\in F[x],$ we can pick a root $\alpha$ of $f(x^2)-x=0.$ Then $F[\alpha^2]=F[\alpha].$ That should cover all counterexamples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true in general. Consider for example $\alpha =1+\sqrt 2, F=\mathbb Q$.

Minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in this case is $p(x)= x^2-2x-1$.

So degree of $F(\alpha)/F=2$ but $\alpha^2= 3+2\sqrt 2\not\in F$

Comment: thanks that clears it. My original problem was different, one of whose subparts I reduced to this so the reduction seems to be wrong. I will post my original problem in a different post.

Answer (score 2):

You always have $[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)]\leq 2$, since $X^2-\alpha^2 \in F(\alpha^2)$ annihilates $\alpha$, and you have $[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)]=1$ if and only if $\alpha^2$ has a root in $F(\alpha^2)$.

This can in fact happen, as the counterexample $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)]=1$ provided by J.W.Tanner shows (which uses the fact that $\zeta_6 = \zeta_3+1$)

Answer (score 1):

There is a general result to this. Suppose $[L : K] = p$ where $p$ is prime. Show that if $M$ is an intermediate field, then $[L:K] = p$ or $1$. From here it is easy to show that if $[K(\alpha):K] = p$ is odd, you will always get $K(\alpha) = K(\alpha^2)$ but if you have that if $p$ is even, you could have that $[K(\alpha^2):K] = 1$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).